# No records return when the value being pass in parameter is from Function

Tags: c#, winforms, string, data-binding, parameters

I'm a VB guy and slowly migrating to C#. Before i go on the main problem, I would like to show you first the function which i used in manipulating the string.

```
class NewString
{
    public static string RemoveExtraSpaces(string xString)
    {
        string iTemp = string.Empty;
        xString = xString.Trim();
        string[] words = xString.Split(' ');
        foreach (string xWor in words)
        {
            string xxWor = xWor.Trim();
            if (xxWor.Length > 0)
            {
                iTemp += " " + xxWor;
            }

        }
        return iTemp;
    }
}
```

The function simply removes all the trailing and extra spaces in the string. For example:

```
NewString.RemoveExtraSpaces("  Stack    OverFlow  ")
==> will return "Stack OverFlow"
```

So my problem is, when i use that function to remove spaces within the string being pass in the parameter, there will be no records binded in the datagridview.

```
    private void LoadCandidateList(bool SearchAll, string iKey)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection xConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand xCOmm = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                xCOmm.Connection = xConn;
                xCOmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                xCOmm.CommandText = "LoadCandidateList";
                xCOmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("LoadAll", Convert.ToInt16(SearchAll));

                string fnlKey = iKey.Trim();
                // when i use the code above, the procedure performs normally
                // but if i use the code below, no records will be return
                // why is that? i prompt it in the MessageBox to check 
                // and displays the correct value.

                // string fnlKey = NewString.RemoveExtraSpaces(iKey.Trim());
                // MessageBox.Show(fnlKey); // => return correct value

                xCOmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("iKey", fnlKey);
                xCOmm.Parameters.AddWithValue("iCurrentID", _CurrentEventID);

                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter xAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(xCOmm))
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            xConn.Open();
                            xAdapter.Fill(ds,"CandidateList");
                            grdResult.DataSource = ds.Tables["CandidateList"];
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Function Error <LoadCandidateList>", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            xConn.Close();
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider dropping the Hungarian Notation for naming your variables. It's somewhat common with VB but not really considered *good form* in C# (e.g. `xConn` vs. `conn`).

Comment: i will take your advise. thank you.

Comment: @Yuck It *used* to be common in old versions of VB where it made more sense (even though the language was strongly typed, a lot of code relied on the weakly-typed `Variant`). In VB.NET, you shouldn’t use it any more than in C#.

Comment: Are you actually getting data back from the database? What does the stored proc do? What does the value of iKey look like?

Comment: @roken, yes. the stored procedure only gets records from db, if i use this `string fnlKey = iKey.Trim();` everything seems fine, but noy when using `// string fnlKey = NewString.RemoveExtraSpaces(iKey.Trim());`

Comment: @johntotetwoo there is actually a very good article on hungarian notation - see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: string.Join(" ", "  Stack    OverFlow  ".Split(new char[] {' '}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

Comment: The first function can be replaced with a single line of code: `string.Join(" ", xString.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: You say it works with Trim(), but not with your function. Is it safe to say that your database doesn't contain "Stack_Overflow" but does contain "Stack_____Overflow"?

Comment: Again, when using RemoveExtraSpaces I assume you do not get any data from the database. Thus this is an issue with your trimming function or database keys and not with your databinding.  Second, what is the value of iKey that works or doesn't work dependent on the trimming method used?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please post your answer below. it works! thank you so much.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight one more thing, how can i make this as an Extension Method? like for example: `string oString = " aa ss ss "; string nString = oString.RemoveExtraSpaces;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function that replaces sequences of spaces with a single space can be re-written in a single line:

```
string.Join(" ", xString.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you would like to make it an extension method, you can do it like this:

```
static class StringExtensions {
    public static string RemoveExtraSpaces(this string xString) {
        return string.Join(" ", xString.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
}
```

Comment: one more thing, how can i make this  as an `Extension Method`? like for example: `string oString = "  aa   ss   ss "; string nString = oString.RemoveExtraSpaces;` ?

Comment: @johntotetwoo Sure, you can make it an extension method. I edited the answer to show the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use the functionality while the data is binded to the Gridview?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='RemoveExtraSpaces(<%# Bind("Name") %>);' AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: It looks like he's using the DataGridView (winforms, not asp.net)

Comment: i sorry sir but i'm using winforms. i forgot to tag it.